# Paypal Sandbox testsite

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-sandbox

I haven't used PayPal sandbox for a while and my latest visit, as always never runs smoothly. Apart from the new interface my account seems OK. and my sandbox  accounts are there, one seller account and one buyer account. I proceed to enter the Sandbox Test site and all it does is loop me back to the live site.

Does anyone know whats going on here! and how do I now access the test site?

Comment: You can directly access the test by visiting this url : www.sandbox.paypal.com . It is same as clicking the "Enter sandbox site" link on developer portal .

Comment: I tried that but it still re-directs to the live site. Or does the url not keep the word sandbox in the url anymore? Really confusing!!

Comment: I just tried to visit the sandbox url and it just redirected me correctly without any issue . You can try to clear your cookies and cache in the browser .

Comment: Sometimes specific links within the sandbox can end up sending you to the live site, but overall everything should be using sandbox.paypal.com without any issue.  I use the sandbox heavily and have not had any problems as of late.  I second clearing your browser cache/cookies and trying again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on cache and cookies Eshan and Andrew-Angell. That sorted the problem.